# How to get data from return in http get function in Angular

Tags: angular, observable, angular-httpclient

this is an example code of get function

```
 someData = this.service.getFunction().subcribe( res => {
     return res.data
 })
```

I expect to get the value as json object from return res.data
but when I console log someData it shows Subcriber {...}.
How can I get the object data instead of Subcriber?
[this is the subcriber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wERU2.png)

Comment: have you tried the solution below?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, write code like this -

```
this.service.getFunction().subcribe(res=>{
    someData =  res.data
});
```

Or If you want to assign value directly use your code like this -

```
someData = this.getData();


getData() {
   return this.service.getFunction().subcribe(res=> {return res.data});
}
```

Comment: I have  tried this way but I still got Subscriber as before